# How to make only towns and addresses to appear in search dropdown using Google API?

Tags: reactjs, google-api

I need to make search input element using Google API and I need to have only towns and addresses listed, and not places. Also, once a user click the town/address in the search list, I need to grab the coordinates because I need them for calling internal Search API. Which Google API do you recommend me to use? I found couple solutions such as Geocoding and Place Autocomplete. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types) parameter for the google Place Autocomplete search is what you're looking for, specifically using the `address` type and `(cities)` type collection.

I also highly recommend the [react-geosuggest](https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) library if you want something pre-made to accomplish this as you can pass those as parameters and style it yourself.

```
<Geosuggest
  types={['address', '(cities)']}
  onSuggestSelect={this.onSuggestSelect}
/>
```

`types` allows you to limit to addresses and cities and `onSuggestSelect` allows you to access the addresses details.

**EDIT**

After looking through the docs a little more I discovered that you can only specify one option for the `types` parameter:

> You may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a
>   certain type by passing a types parameter. The parameter specifies a
>   type or a type collection, as listed in the supported types below. If
>   nothing is specified, all types are returned. In general only a single
>   type is allowed. The exception is that you can safely mix the geocode
>   and establishment types, but note that this will have the same effect
>   as specifying no types.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types

So out of the following options

- `geocode` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results, rather than business results. Generally, you use this request to disambiguate results where the location specified may be indeterminate.
- `address` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.
- `establishment` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only business results.
- the `(regions)` type collection instructs the Places service to return any result matching the following types:

  - `locality`
  - `sublocality`
  - `postal_code`
  - `country`
  - `administrative_area_level_1`
  - `administrative_area_level_2`
- the `(cities)` type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3`.

I would say your best option would either be `address`, `(cities)`, or `(regions)` depending on how specific you need the output to be.